# Fail to install dataprep library on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to use dataprep on Python. I tried to install it with this command

`!pip install dataprep`  on Jupyter Notebook. I have tried find the solution all over the internet. I have tried to install through Anaconda CMD but still failed. The failed output error is like this; ​Anyone has the solution?

```
 Building wheels for collected packages: bottleneck
  Building wheel for bottleneck (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for bottleneck (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build bottleneck
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc2rt_tpk'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d3qw7kcm\bottleneck_032fd76987774d54a306e1730d779cf3
  Complete output (51 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\_pytesttester.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
  copying bottleneck\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\autotimeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench_detailed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
  copying bottleneck\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\move.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce_axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\reduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
  copying bottleneck\slow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\bn_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\bn_template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
  copying bottleneck\src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\input_modification_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\list_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\memory_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\move_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_axis_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\reduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\scalar_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  copying bottleneck\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
  UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck/_version.py
  set build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck/_version.py to '1.3.2'
  running build_ext
  running config
  compiling '_configtest.c':
  
  
  
  int __attribute__((optimize("O3"))) have_attribute_optimize_opt_3(void*);
  
  int main(void)
  {
      return 0;
  }
  
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottleneck
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bottleneck, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
1
```

Comment: Could you confirm if you are using [Google Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep) and your Jupyter Notebook instance is running in AI Platform or Vertex AI ?

Comment: I am sorry. It just dataprep library and not google. This is the link https://dataprep.ai/

Comment: The solution is provided in the error message itself: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"